# How can I make this css grid fit the page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, socket.io

The grid is supposed to make an 11 x 11 image keyboard for a chatroom using socket.io.

The keyboard is a grid element, set to 100vh height, 100vw width, but isn't displaying as such.

```
/* CSS for chatroom layout */
.chat-container {
    display: flex;
    height: 100vh;
}

.chat-sidebar {
    flex: 0 0 200px;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    padding: 20px;
}

.chat-messages {
    flex: 1;
    padding: 20px;
}

.message-list {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
}

.message-item {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

/* CSS for image keyboard layout */
.image-keyboard {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(11, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(11, 1fr);
    gap: 5px;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
}

.image-key {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
//    grid-row: auto / span 1;
//    grid-column: auto / span 1;
}



    .image-key img {
        max-width: 100%;
        max-height: 100%;
    }

    .image-key .definition {
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: -30px;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #333;
        color: #fff;
        padding: 5px;
        font-size: 12px;
    }

    .image-key:hover .definition {
        display: block;
    }
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Chatroom with Image Keyboard</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="chat-container">
        <div class="chat-sidebar">
            <h1>Chatroom</h1>
            <ul class="message-list"></ul>
        </div>
        <div class="chat-messages">
            <div class="image-keyboard" id="keyboard"></div>
            <div class="definitions" id="definitions"></div>
            <form>
                <input type="text" id="message-input" placeholder="Type your message...">
                <button type="submit">Send</button>
            </form>
            <ul class="chat-log" id="chat-log"></ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="client.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

client.js

```
const keyboardContainer = document.querySelector('.image-keyboard');

// Define the image sources and titles for each key
const keyData = [
    { src: '/images/t_1-me.png', title: 'me', definition: 'me, I, my' },
    { src: '/images/t_2-we.png', title: 'we', definition: 'we, us, our' },
    { src: '/images/t_3-you.png', title: 'you', definition: 'you, your' },
    { src: '/images/t_4-they.png', title: 'you', definition: 'you, your' },
    { src: '/images/t_5-of.png', title: 'of', definition: 'you, your' },
    { src: '/images/t_6-good.png', title: 'good', definition: 'you, your' },
    { src: '/images/t_7-bad.png', title: 'you', definition: 'you, your' },
    { src: '/images/t_8-emphasis.png', title: 'you', definition: 'you, your' },
    { src: '/images/t_9-comma.png', title: 'you', definition: 'you, your' },
    { src: '/images/t_10-yes.png', title: 'you', definition: 'you, your' },
    { src: '/images/t_11-no.png', title: 'you', definition: 'you, your' },
    { src: '/images/t_12-place.png', title: 'you', definition: 'you, your' },
    { src: '/images/t_13-full stop.png', title: 'you', definition: 'you, your' },
    { src: '/images/t_14-question mark.png', title: 'you', definition: 'you, your' },
    { src: '/images/t_15-be.png', title: 'you', definition: 'you, your' },
    { src: '/images/t_16-different.png', title: 'you', definition: 'you, your' },
    { src: '/images/t_17-almost.png', title: 'you', definition: 'you, your' },
    { src: '/images/t_18-or.png', title: 'you', definition: 'you, your' },
    { src: '/images/t_19-wait.png', title: 'you', definition: 'you, your' },
    { src: '/images/t_20-ing.png', title: 'you', definition: 'you, your' },
    { src: '/images/t_21-and.png', title: 'you', definition: 'you, your' },
    { src: '/images/t_22-but.png', title: 'you', definition: 'you, your' },
    { src: '/images/t_23-become.png', title: 'you', definition: 'you, your' },
    { src: '/images/t_24-past tense indicator.png', title: 'you', definition: 'you, your' },
    { src: '/images/t_25-less.png', title: 'you', definition: 'you, your' },
    { src: '/images/t_26-more.png', title: 'you', definition: 'you, your' },
    { src: '/images/t_27-exclamation mark.png', title: 'you', definition: 'you, your' },
    { src: '/images/t_28-number.png', title: 'you', definition: 'you, your' },
    { src: '/images/t_29-one.png', title: 'you', definition: 'you, your' },
    { src: '/images/t_30-two.png', title: 'you', definition: 'you, your' },
    { src: '/images/t_31-three.png', title: 'me', definition: 'me, I, my' },
    { src: '/images/t_32-hand.png', title: 'we', definition: 'we, us, our' },
    { src: '/images/t_33-do.png', title: 'you', definition: 'you, your' },
    { src: '/images/t_34-have.png', title: 'you', definition: 'you, your' },
    { src: '/images/t_35-to be able to.png', title: 'you', definition: 'you, your' },
    { src: '/images/t_36-use.png', title: 'you', definition: 'you, your' },
    { src: '/images/t_37-say.png', title: 'you', definition: 'you, your' },
    { src: '/images/t_38-give.png', title: 'you', definition: 'you, your' },
    { src: '/images/t_39-love.png', title: 'you', definition: 'you, your' },
    { src: '/images/t_40-feel.png', title: 'you', definition: 'you, your' },
    { src: '/images/t_41-know.png', title: 'you', definition: 'you, your' },
    { src: '/images/t_42-head.png', title: 'you', definition: 'you, your' },
    { src: '/images/t_43-look.png', title: 'you', definition: 'you, your' },
    { src: '/images/t_44-listen.png', title: 'you', definition: 'you, your' },
    { src: '/images/t_45-nose.png', title: 'you', definition: 'you, your' },
    { src: '/images/t_46-mouth.png', title: 'you', definition: 'you, your' },
    { src: '/images/t_47-please.png', title: 'you', definition: 'you, your' },
    { src: '/images/t_48-need.png', title: 'you', definition: 'you, your' },
    { src: '/images/t_49-many.png', title: 'you', definition: 'you, your' },
    { src: '/images/t_50-small.png', title: 'you', definition: 'you, your' },
    { src: '/images/t_51-big.png', title: 'you', definition: 'you, your' },
    { src: '/images/t_52-time.png', title: 'you', definition: 'you, your' },
    { src: '/images/t_53-old.png', title: 'you', definition: 'you, your' },
    { src: '/images/t_54-future.png', title: 'you', definition: 'you, your' },
    { src: '/images/t_55-young.png', title: 'you', definition: 'you, your' },
    { src: '/images/t_56-new.png', title: 'you', definition: 'you, your' },
    { src: '/images/t_57-year.png', title: 'you', definition: 'you, your' },
    { src: '/images/t_58-light.png', title: 'you', definition: 'you, your' },
    { src: '/images/t_59-this.png', title: 'you', definition: 'you, your' },
    { src: '/images/t_60-that.png', title: 'me', definition: 'me, I, my' },
    { src: '/images/t_61-next to.png', title: 'we', definition: 'we, us, our' },
    { src: '/images/t_62-centre.png', title: 'you', definition: 'you, your' },
    { src: '/images/t_63-top.png', title: 'you', definition: 'you, your' },
    { src: '/images/t_64-front.png', title: 'you', definition: 'you, your' },
    { src: '/images/t_65-back.png', title: 'you', definition: 'you, your' },
    { src: '/images/t_66-from.png', title: 'you', definition: 'you, your' },
    { src: '/images/t_67-thing.png', title: 'you', definition: 'you, your' },
    { src: '/images/t_68-all or everything.png', title: 'you', definition: 'you, your' },
    { src: '/images/t_69-earth.png', title: 'you', definition: 'you, your' },
    { src: '/images/t_70-room or bedroom.png', title: 'you', definition: 'you, your' },
    { src: '/images/t_71-door.png', title: 'you', definition: 'you, your' },
    { src: '/images/t_72-person.png', title: 'you', definition: 'you, your' },
    { src: '/images/t_73-fire.png', title: 'you', definition: 'you, your' },
    { src: '/images/t_74-cold.png', title: 'you', definition: 'you, your' },
    { src: '/images/t_75-water.png', title: 'you', definition: 'you, your' },
    { src: '/images/t_76-air.png', title: 'you', definition: 'you, your' },
    { src: '/images/t_77-to.png', title: 'you', definition: 'you, your' },
    { src: '/images/t_78-hard object.png', title: 'you', definition: 'you, your' },
    { src: '/images/t_79-plant.png', title: 'you', definition: 'you, your' },
    { src: '/images/t_80-fruit.png', title: 'you', definition: 'you, your' },
    { src: '/images/t_81-food.png', title: 'you', definition: 'you, your' },
    { src: '/images/t_82-carbohydrate food.png', title: 'you', definition: 'you, your' },
    { src: '/images/t_83-animal.png', title: 'you', definition: 'you, your' },
    { src: '/images/t_84-cute.png', title: 'you', definition: 'you, your' },
    { src: '/images/t_85-fish.png', title: 'you', definition: 'you, your' },
    { src: '/images/t_86-bird.png', title: 'you', definition: 'you, your' },
    { src: '/images/t_87-virus.png', title: 'you', definition: 'you, your' },
    { src: '/images/t_88-store.png', title: 'you', definition: 'you, your' },
    { src: '/images/t_89-device.png', title: 'me', definition: 'me, I, my' },
    { src: '/images/t_90-broken.png', title: 'we', definition: 'we, us, our' },
    { src: '/images/t_91-electric.png', title: 'you', definition: 'you, your' },
    { src: '/images/t_92-virtual reality.png', title: 'you', definition: 'you, your' },
    { src: '/images/t_93-cord.png', title: 'you', definition: 'you, your' },
    { src: '/images/t_94-red.png', title: 'you', definition: 'you, your' },
    { src: '/images/t_95-yellow.png', title: 'you', definition: 'you, your' },
    { src: '/images/t_96-blue.png', title: 'you', definition: 'you, your' },
    { src: '/images/t_97-white.png', title: 'you', definition: 'you, your' },
    { src: '/images/t_98-colour.png', title: 'you', definition: 'you, your' },
    { src: '/images/t_99-image.png', title: 'you', definition: 'you, your' },
    { src: '/images/t_100-name.png', title: 'you', definition: 'you, your' },
    { src: '/images/t_101-book.png', title: 'you', definition: 'you, your' },
    { src: '/images/t_102-clothing.png', title: 'you', definition: 'you, your' },
    { src: '/images/t_103-skin.png', title: 'you', definition: 'you, your' },
    { src: '/images/t_104-sculpting.png', title: 'you', definition: 'you, your' },
    { src: '/images/t_105-money.png', title: 'you', definition: 'you, your' },
    { src: '/images/t_106-woman.png', title: 'you', definition: 'you, your' },
    { src: '/images/t_107-man.png', title: 'you', definition: 'you, your' },
    { src: '/images/t_108-parent.png', title: 'you', definition: 'you, your' },
    { src: '/images/t_109-dead.png', title: 'you', definition: 'you, your' },
    { src: '/images/t_110-sleep.png', title: 'you', definition: 'you, your' },
    { src: '/images/t_111-night.png', title: 'you', definition: 'you, your' },
    { src: '/images/t_112-unusual.png', title: 'you', definition: 'you, your' },
    { src: '/images/t_113-laugh.png', title: 'you', definition: 'you, your' },
    { src: '/images/t_114-way.png', title: 'you', definition: 'you, your' },
    { src: '/images/t_115-foot.png', title: 'you', definition: 'you, your' },
    { src: '/images/t_116-start.png', title: 'you', definition: 'you, your' },
    { src: '/images/t_117-container.png', title: 'you', definition: 'you, your' },
    { src: '/images/t_118-table.png', title: 'you', definition: 'you, your' },
    { src: '/images/t_119-sex.png', title: 'you', definition: 'you, your' },
    { src: '/images/t_120-difficult.png', title: 'you', definition: 'you, your' },
    { src: '/images/t_121-strong.png', title: 'you', definition: 'you, your' },


];

// Loop through the key data and create a key element for each
for (let i = 0; i < keyData.length; i++) {
    const key = document.createElement('div');
    key.classList.add('key');
   key.setAttribute('title', keyData[i].title); // Set the title attribute for the key
   key.setAttribute('definition', keyData[i].definition); // Set the definition attribute for the key
    const img = document.createElement('img');
    img.setAttribute('src', keyData[i].src);
    img.setAttribute('alt', keyData[i].title);
    key.appendChild(img);
    keyboardContainer.appendChild(key);
}
```

[How it displays at 100%](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1UqeN.png)
[How it displays at 25%](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZlM7t.png)

**Troubleshooting:**

I set the height/width of image-keyboard to 100vh and 100vw respectively.

I tried adding

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

but nothing changed. Changing the gap didn't help either.

I tried changing image-key to

```
.image-key {
    width: calc((100% - 10 * 5px) / 11);
    height: calc((100% - 10 * 5px) / 11);
    background-color: #ccc;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
}
```

but the same.